# Entity Framework Implicit Type Conversion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, type-conversion

Lets say I have an account number in the format of `YYYY-NNNNNC`, where `Y` is a Year digit, `N` is a number, and `C` is a Luhn checksum digit.

Example: `2016-426013`

It can exist as a string with all the information that it would have if it were in class form:

```
public class AccountNumber
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Checksum { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in my application I would much rather be dealing with this nice object than a string that I may need to parse. But in the database it is almost necessary for it to exist as a string.

I've written my implicit conversions

```
public static implicit operator string(AccountNumber an)
```

And

```
public static implicit operator AccountNumber(string s)
```

Is there any way that I can make EF store a class like this:

```
public class Account
{
    public AccountNumber AccountNumber { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

But have it convert the `AccountNumber` to and from a `string` for the purposes of database storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: [Value conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) are supported in EF Core 2.1 and onward.**

This is one of the most requested features of EF, but is not yet present. Type conversions. So for the moment, you need to use a string data type to deal with EF. And wrap it with another AccountNumber property, which does a GET/SET on it internally.

The implicit operators won't work yet, because the AccountNumber entiry has to be constructed in the SQL domain of things, and hence it is going to come back as a string always. Post that, you could do a type conversion, and maybe that is what EF team will come up with.

But for the moment, you either need to have explicit wrapper properties which does the conversion for you.. or have extension/helper methods to deal with it.

Comment: Rats... At least we have a work around. For completeness, here is a [link to the feature request](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2639292-simple-type-mapping-or-mapped-type-conversion-supp)

Comment: thanks @AdamSchiavone for the link. i edited my answer to add the link for others